# what is the difference between reference time and event time

Tags: terminology, verbs, tense, tense-aspect-mood

what is the difference between reference time and event time , also i am native Arabic speaker , i tried to translate by google translate two examples the reference time before and after event time but difference is not recognized in Arabic

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69820/reference-speech-and-event-time